# Ruby equivalent of Perls one line string replacer

Tags: ruby, perl, terminal

With perl, you can do this:

`$ perl -pi -e 's/foo/bar/g' *.txt`

Which will replace the string "foo" with "bar" on all *.txt files in the current directory.

I like this, but I was wondering if the same thing is possible using Ruby.

Comment: Run `ruby -h` and see what it says.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep. Ruby has an equivalent for most of Perl's command line options, and many of them are identical.

```sh
$ ruby -pi -e 'gsub /foo/, "bar"' *.txt
```

Here are the relevant docs from `man ruby`:

> - **`-i extension`** – Specifies in-place-edit mode. The extension,
>     if specified, is added to old file name to make a backup copy. For
>     example:
>
>   ```sh
>   % echo matz > /tmp/junk
>   % cat /tmp/junk
>   matz
>   % ruby -p -i.bak -e '$_.upcase!' /tmp/junk
>   % cat /tmp/junk
>   MATZ
>   % cat /tmp/junk.bak
>   matz
>   ```
> - **`-n`** – Causes Ruby to assume the following loop around your
>     script, which makes it iterate over file name arguments somewhat like
>     `sed -n` or `awk`.
>
>   ```ruby
>   while gets
>     ...
>   end
>   ```
> - **`-p`** – Acts mostly same as `-n` switch, but print the value of
>     variable `$_` at the each end of the loop. For example:
>
>   ```sh
>   % echo matz | ruby -p -e '$_.tr! "a-z", "A-Z"'
>   MATZ
>   ```

My code above uses [`Kernel#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-gsub), which is only available in `-p`/`-n` mode. Per the docs:

> **gsub(pattern, replacement) → $_**
>   **gsub(pattern) {|...| block } → $_**
>
> Equivalent to `$_.gsub...`, except that `$_` will be updated if
>   substitution occurs. Available only when `-p`/`-n` command line option
>   specified.

There are a handful of other such Kernel methods, which are useful to know: [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-chomp), [`chop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-chop), and (naturally) [`sub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sub).

Check out `man ruby`; there are a lot of great features.